# Whats the best server-language for programing a Webcrawler?

Tags: perl, coldfusion, asp, web-crawler

I would like to ask what language:

**ASP.NET / Ruby / CGI / Perl / Python / ColdFusion...**

would be the bes for programming a Webcrawler

and for processing the contained information????

(it should be used for Data-Mining)

> > Fastest at runtime? Easiest to write? Easiest to maintain?<<

Thanks

Comment: please don't vote to migrate to SO - this is as off topic there as "what is the best server" would be here.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Questions about programming languages are off topic *here* but may be asked on our sister site, stackoverflow.com. However, questions of the type you're asking here ("what is the best...") are considered off topic on most stack exchange sites, certainly both this one and stack overflow. If you want help with designing and building your App, I know that Stack Overflow will love to help you, but you will need to come up with a more focussed question for them. Also, there's a lot to be said for Sergii's answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language you know the best.